# Instantiating a list of structs in C

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading, coding-style, struct

I'm sure this must have been asked before but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere.  I have a struct defined in a header file as so:

```
struct lock {
    char *name;
    // add what you need here
    void *holder;
    // (don't forget to mark things volatile as needed)
};
```

I want to make a list of lock objects.  That way I can say something like:

```
lock_list[0] = create_lock();
lock_list[1] = create_lock();
```

I tried different ways but they all give me errors.  I thought I could simply say:

```
lock[2] lock_list;
```

but it didn't work.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: try lock lock_list[2];  or struct lock lock_list[2];

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `create_lock()` returns a pointer to a `lock`, the following should work:

```
lock *lock_list[2];
```

---

Also, since you didn't post it, you need to `typedef` your `struct` if you want to be able to omit the `struct` part when using it:

```
typedef struct lock lock;
```

Comment: I don't see a typedef. Perhaps he needs `struct lock *lock_list[2]`. (Or, perhaps `struct lock lock_list[2]`, depending on the return type of `create_lock`.)

Comment: @Rob Yes I just noticed that.  I will try 'struct lock* lock_list[2]' .  Thanx for the quick reply

Answer (score 5):

If it's not fixed size, you can produce a linked list:

```
typedef struct lock_t lock;
typedef struct lockList_t lockList;

struct lock_t {
    char *name;
    void *holder;
}

struct lockList_t {
    lock lock_entry;
    lockList *lock_next;
}
```

You can then use an instance of lockList to store a dynamically sized list of locks.

Comment: thanx I'll keep that in mind for the future but for now it's a constant length 4.